# Find amount of installed memory on QNX system

Tags: qnx

How do I find the amount of memory installed on my QNX Neutrino system?

- `uname -a` doesn't show it
- `top` only shows how much memory is available
- I've looked at `pidin syspage` without success
- `pidin mem` shows all the used memory in gory detail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The amount of free RAM is the size of "/proc" !

In your own program, you can write something like this :

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
struct stat buf;
if (stat("/proc", &buf) != -1) {
    printf("Mem free = %d\n", buf.st_size);
}
```

--
Hope this help
Emmanuel

Answer (score 6):

`pidin info` will show the amount of memory installed, as shown below.

```
pidin info
CPU:X86 Release:6.4.1  FreeMem:836Mb/1015Mb BootTime:Jun 04 14:01:55 UTC 2014
```

Answer (score 4):

showmem -S will show the amount of RAM memory installed as shown below,

## showmem -S

System RAM:     1936M (    2030043136) 
 Total Used:      401M (     420642376) 
 Used Private:   317M (     332529404) 
 Used Shared:     79M (      83333120) 
 Other:   4667K (       4779852) (includes IFS and reserved RAM)

Comment: Awesome! I can't believe I didn't see that one. Your answer is better than mine. :-) Thanks a bunch.