# Retrieving showmem output on QNX

Tags: qnx

Does QNX store the output of showmem system call in some file?

*showmem -S*
System RAM:     4096M (    4294967296)
Total Used:     1425M (    1494345552)
Used Private:   1075M (    1127446352)
Used Shared:     349M (     366899200)

Answer (score 0):

take a look at
[my reply to a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040046/find-amount-of-installed-memory-on-qnx-system/33523358#33523358)

I wrote a sample code to get the available RAM.

Hope this help

Emmanuel